# TabBarView swipe event listener

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to `setState()` whenever a `TabBarView` **will change** its index on swipe.

```
TabBarView(
  controller: _tabController,
  children: [
    fooScreen(),
    barScreen(),
  ]
```

So far I've been able to use `_tabController.addListener()` but this only triggers whenever the `TabBarView` index has already changed. Is there any way to get it to trigger when the index is going to change?

Answer (score 1):

Since you need your event to get triggered **on swipe** then you could wrap the widget you are interested in listening for the **swipe gesture**.

In code this could be achieved using the `GestureDetector` (which I'm sure you've used already).

```
GestureDetector(
 child: yourWidget,

 onPanUpdate: (d) {
  if (d.delta.dx > 0) {
    //triggered when swiped yourWidget in right direction
  }
});
```

Comment: That would only help me to know if the user has swiped left or right, but it won't tell me if the TabBarView index is going to change. You could swipe right and stop dragging without actually changing the slide and staying at the same index.

Comment: Btw, I don't know why but pan update events don't work with a TabBarView nested inside a GestureDetector...